# implementing random generator in cuda

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, nvidia

i want to implement this function in cuda as device/global function so as to obtain random numbers which are in gaussian distribution.

```
double gasdev2() {
double ran3n(long *seed);
//  double genrand64_real3();
static int iset=0;
static double gcos;
double tmp1,tmp2;

if (iset==0) { 
 tmp1=sqrt(-2*log(ran3n(&seed)));
 tmp2=pi2*ran3n(&seed);
//    tmp1=sqrt(-2*log(genrand64_real3()));
//    tmp2=pi2*genrand64_real3();
  gcos=tmp1*cos(tmp2);
 iset=1;
 return tmp1*sin(tmp2);
//return 1;
}else{
  iset=0;
  return gcos;
 //return 1;
}
}
```

this function will be basically used in these function calls and in serial code these are like this

```
  for(int i=0;i<NTO;i++){
  Frdx[j]=gasdev2()*ranm[j]*tconst;
  Frdy[j]=gasdev2()*ranm[j]*tconst;
  Frdz[j]=gasdev2()*ranm[j]*tconst;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest not implementing it yourself but using the random algorithms provided by [Thrust](http://thrust.github.io/doc/classthrust_1_1random_1_1uniform__real__distribution.html):

```
 uint32_t seed = 1234;
 thrust::default_random_engine rng(seed);
 thrust::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(0.0f, 1.0f);
 float random_value_1 = dist(rng);
 float random_value_2 = dist(rng);
```

You can use this both in host and device code.
Have a look at the [Thrust examples](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/monte_carlo.cu).